# What's the difference between Cut the Rope 2 and Cut the Rope 2: Om Nom's Adventure

Tags: version-differences, cut-the-rope-2

In the iOS App Store, what's the difference between Cut the Rope 2 (*[$1.99](https://appsto.re/us/IG6OO.i)*) and Cut the Rope 2: Om Nom's Adventure (*[Free](https://appsto.re/us/ghneV.i)*)?

Initially I thought the two were separate games, or that the free version may have been a demo, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Both pages feature near identical trailers, screenshots, and app descriptions. My only guess is that maybe the free version might contain more ads?

Comment: The only difference I found is version number and last update. Both seem to feature in-app purchases.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not downloaded either app, this is entirely my speculation based on the descriptions.

It seems that the free version has an extra section in the description that is not present in the paid version.

> SUBSCRIPTION. Subscribe to Premium Membership and get premium experience with Cut the Rope 2!
>
> By subscribing to Cut the Rope 2, you:
>
> - Disable Ads
> - Disable IAPs
> - Get Free starter pack with power-ups after subscription purchase
> - Get Free coins daily
>
> You can choose three subscription options with varying lengths. You can subscribe for 1 month, 3 months or for 6 months.
>
> Subscription cost is $2.99/$5.99/$7.99 for 1/3/6 months. If you choose to purchase Premium Membership Subscription Pack through iTunes Store, your account will be charged upon confirmation of purchase. Your subscription will auto-renew every month/3 months/6 months unless you turn it off 24-hours prior to the end of the current period.
>
> You can turn off auto-renewal at any time from your iTunes account settings.
>
> No cancellation of the current subscription is allowed during an active subscription period. If you don’t choose to purchase subscription, you can simply continue using Cut the Rope 2 for free.
>
> Terms and Conditions:
>
> https://www.zeptolab.com/terms

My guess is that the paid version has fewer advertisements.